# Clicking button on a dialog in webpage with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select the Print button that appears in a dialog after I click elsewhere on the original page. Doing so manually and inspecting shows the following:

[image: html]

Copying the xpath to that last element and using:

```py
prnt = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[42]/div/section/div/div/ul/li[7]")))
prnt.click()
```

yields selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
This happens even though I can see the dialog on the page when the code is running, so I am at a loss.

Comment: what is the element you need to click first in order to open the dialog?

Comment: I have to right click anywhere on the page, and then this custom dialog appears

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.